# Trying to update a nested geoip location field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

### Here is what I've tried:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.geoip += newElement",
    "params": {
        "newElement": {
           "location" : "[40.730610, -73.935242]"
        }
    },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "CITY": {
        "value": "nyc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above throws error *Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [params].*

### Second Attempt:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
    "source":
      "for (item in ctx._source.geoip){item.location = '[40.730610, -73.935242]'}",
      "lang":"painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "CITY": {
        "value": "nyc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above throws null pointer exception, and points to the  period at source.geoip

### I also tried changing the value of location to just *test* but receive the same errors.

Here is my mapping:

```
{
  "orders" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "geoip" : {
          "dynamic" : "true",
          "properties" : {
            "location" : {
              "type" : "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
     }
}
```

### I am using ES v7.2 and Kibana v7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues in the 1st approach:

- `params` need to be defined within the script object, not below it
- `newElement` needs to be accessed using `params.newElement`
- you cannot append `+= params.newElement` to a nonexistent `ctx._source.geoip`
- you cannot append an object to a single-value field -- you can just assign it
- `location` is of the `geo_point` type, so either `[40.730610, -73.935242]` (`[lon, lat]`) or `"-73.935242,40.730610"` (`"lat,lon"`), but not a mixture of both

Working command:

```
POST orders/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.geoip = params.newElement",
    "params": {
      "newElement": {
        "location": [
          40.73061,
          -73.935242
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "CITY": {
        "value": "nyc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```